# Get Name by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get name, but I can't get it, only the id but not the name,

```
<div class='post'>
<input name='postid_15' type='text' value='15'/>
<input name='postname_15' type='hidden' class='names' value='John'/> Position 1</div>

<div class='post'><input name='postid_20' type='hidden' value='20' /> 
<input name='postname_15' type='hidden' class='names' value='Frank'/> Position 2</div>


<pre>
(function ($){
    $(document).on('click','.post',function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).find('names').val());
    });
})(jQuery);
</pre>
```

I have done the exercise here
https://jsfiddle.net/kz1gybL9/1/

Answer (score 0):

The reference 'names' needs to be looking for the class and should be updated to '.names'.

```
(function ($){
    $(document).on('click','.post',function(e){
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).find('.names').val());
    });
})(jQuery);
```